# Sonos Sample Server Authentication Error

Tags: sonos

I am currently in the beginnings of developing an integrated Sonos app, and to get a better understanding of what needs to happen, I downloaded Sonos's provided sample server for the "Acme" service.

On first use, I was able to get it working and was able to play songs from the static directory that was provided within the package. However, after closing the server, leaving my computer for some time, and booting it back up again with `./gradlew bootRun`, I noticed that I was not able to use the sample service anymore. On the window to link the sample account, it said that there was an error in authenticating and that it might be an issue with the connection.

First things first, I rebooted everything I could reboot. Turned the gradle server on then off. Removed the service and created it again. I even did a factory reset and put the Sonos device (PLAY:1 variety) on a different network at the office. The sample service still won't authenticate.

What could be causing the authentication for the sample Acme service to stop working just like that on every network? I should mention that I have been using the same config settings ever since I got it to work the first time, so it should not be a problem with my configurations in the customSD page. Also, I have not changed any code within the sample server.

**TL;DR:** The Sonos sample server worked one time for me, and hasn't worked since on multiple networks and devices, even after a factory reset. What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the player possibly can't find the sample server any more. When you set up the service via customsd, you used an ip address for the endpoint. Is it possible that ip address has changed?